# Merging config files in git

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository that contains config files.

I clone the repository to create an instance and edit the config files.

When I need to pull the latest version I stash the config files and then pop them after the pull.

However sometimes there is a change to a repository config file. This means that the local config file needs merging into the repository version, but this merged file should not be pushed back to the repository.

How do I do this?

Comment: It might be better to handle this programmatically — have a config file containing defaults, but allow for a local, non-committed override file, and merge the config when loading them into your application.

Comment: @cmbuckley Good idea. However that would add to the amount of processing for every page load. I could get around that by caching the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and use [`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index), once the merge is done (but not staged yet):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- yourConfigFile
```

Any change would not be visible from the index

(the later `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- yourConfigFile`)

Answer (score 0):

After you pop, there should be an automatic merge.

The problem is that when git has finished the automatic merge, it may have marked the file as "need to be committed". What you ask, in fact, is *how to "reset" this mark?*, the solution is then :

```
git reset --mixed HEAD
```

From the man page :

```
   git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
       This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the working tree depending on <mode>. If <mode> is omitted,
       defaults to "--mixed". The <mode> must be one of the following:

    [...]

       --mixed
           Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.
```

As you can see `--mixed` can be ommitted as it is the default mode.